# Tomcat http is not redirecting to https

Tags: http, tomcat, redirect, https

I have two instances of Tomcat set up on two different servers. I didn't explicitly select which versions to install, they were actually both automatically installed as a part of IBM Rational Team Concert installations (v5.0.1 and v5.0.2 on each server), but I can say they are both at least version 7.

On the first instance, when I go to http://myserver.domain.com:9443/ccm, I get automatically redirected to https://myserver.domain.com:9443/ccm.

On the second instance, when I go to http://otherserver.domain.com:9443/ccm, I do not get redirected to https, but rather either get a strange download or get a blank page with an unrecognizable Unicode character (depending on the browser).

I notice that both server.xml's are different (I am not sure why RTC made them *that* different between minor releases), but it is not obvious by looking at them both what I have to set in the second server.xml to achieve the behavior present in the first. Port 9443 is set up as an HTTPS port. What do I set in server.xml to make all http requests to that port automatically redirect to https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat can't do what you are asking. There is no mechanism to detect that http is being used on an https port and redirect the user accordingly. This might be something we add in Tomcat 9 but that is very much just an idea at this stage.

Something other than Tomcat is performing the redirect you observe. Take a look at the HTTP headers - they might provide some clue as to what is going on.